# How to get the number of bars since a condition was met in different timeframes?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i want to plot the number of bars since it rises up the moving average ( close > ma ) 20 and the moving average must make rising price (ma > ma[1]), if any of these two conditions is break, the bar counter should reset to 0. i want to calculate the 4 hours timeframe bars and moving average, but when i switch to 2 hours, the value returned is changing

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © jeckwilke

//@version=5
indicator("My script")

ma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", ta.sma(close, 20))
lma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", ta.sma(close[1], 20))
_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", close)
var counter = 0
if _close > ma and ma > lma
    counter += 1
else
    counter := 0

plot(counter)
```

[553BARS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKcCX.png)
In this case, it is counting the bars in the 5 minute timeframe.

i want the 4 hours timeframe bars value on 5 minutes timeframe, [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wrJF.png) but in others timeframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my post accordingly.

**This is the result...**

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

my_function() =>
    float sma20 = ta.sma(close, 20)
    bool is_crossover = ta.crossover(close, sma20)
    bool is_crossunder = ta.crossunder(close, sma20)
    bool is_rising = ta.rising(sma20, 1)

    int barssince_crossover  = ta.barssince(is_crossover)
    int barssince_crossunder = ta.barssince(is_crossunder)

    //log.info(str.format("\nis_crossover: {0}\nis_crossunder: {1}\nis_rising: {2}\nbarssince_crossover: {3}\nbarssince_crossunder: {4}", is_crossover, is_crossunder, is_rising, barssince_crossover, barssince_crossunder))

    if barssince_crossunder > barssince_crossover and is_rising
        barssince_crossover
    else
        0

int counter  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", my_function())

plot(counter)
```

**What I did...**

I created a function with all the stuff that is needed and put that into `request.*()`.
[HERE](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/User-defined_functions.html) you can read about functions.

All `ta.*()` functions are self explanetory.
When you hover your mouse over it or use `STRG+MouseClick`
it will pop-up an Information on how to use them.

---

**Addtion...**

> i want to reset the counter when the moving average decreases and
> starts counting from 0 again.

Change the variable name of the request output and add a new persistent variable to the game.
The simple `if` statement counts your bars then.

```
int barssince  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", my_function())

var counter = int(0)

if barssince > 0
    counter += 1
else 
    counter := 0

plot(counter)
```

This will count the bars on your chart and not those in HTF.

When you want to count the bars of HTF instead
then you have to change the end of the function into this...

```
var counter = int(0)

if barssince_crossunder > barssince_crossover and is_rising
    counter += 1
else
    counter := 0
counter
```

---

**As a side note...**
You have to use `barmerge.lookahead_on`
when accessing historical data via `[]` within `request.*()`,
other wise it will result in unpredictable garbage.

You should read about [Repainting](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Repainting.html#repainting-request-security-calls), and then about [Future Leaks](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Repainting.html#future-leak-with-request-security).

Comment: Its working fine in the 4 hours timeframe, but when i switch to 2 hours or another one, the value is changing as well. https://imgur.com/a/WUpNPWA


I want the value of 27 bars of 4hours timeframe in each timeframe

Comment: @EduardoMoreira sure the value is changing once every four hours, cause this is what it takes into account. And on every timeframe the output will look different, cause this is what it suppose to do. I assume you want some complete different. what value do you want and why 27 of them? please elaborate

Comment: i want to plot the number of bars since it rises up the moving average ( close > ma ) 20 and the moving average  must make rising price (ma > ma[1]), if any of these two conditions is break, the bar counter should reset to 0. i want to calculate the 4 hours timeframe bars and moving average, but when i switch to 2 hours, the value returned is changing.

Comment: @EduardoMoreira this explanation I understand, and this is what you should write in your post. Please update you post via [Edit Button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77212620/edit) and I will come up with a solution for that.

Comment: sorry about my explanation, english is not my native language =/ its kinda hard to explain these things. 

I already changed the post, thx for your patience

Comment: @EduardoMoreira done :)

Comment: thx, it works fine! i just found an issue that i dont know how to fix, i want to reset the counter when the moving average decreases and starts counting from 0 again.
in this case its returning 0 when the moving average decreases, but the counter is returning the counter from the last value (8).
https://imgur.com/a/miWLpIm

Comment: @EduardoMoreira done